# F# Connecting to MSAccess 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: ms-access, f#, ms-access-2010

I cannot for the life of me connect to MS Access 2010 from within F# on my 32-bit Windows 7 machine.

```
let path = @"C:\Users\...\db.accdb"
let s = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=" + path + ";Persist Security Info=False;"
let conn = new OleDbConnection(s)
do conn.Open()
```

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find installable ISAM.

Is there a better way to go about this? I do not have administrative rights to install any additional software, such as missing drivers, on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong connections string

```
 Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=
```

In full

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

The Jet drivers are for MS Access prior to 2007, the *.mbd format.

See also: http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: You are missing a space in Data Source, I have corrected it above.